# Does using PHP headers during login make the form vulnerable to attacks?

Tags: php, exploit, vulnerability, header

I didn't think so, but upon reading online it seems this type of code is vulnerable as I'm not ending with `exit();` and could therefore be exploited by redirecting or changing the contents of the headers.

I've tried exploiting it using BurpSuite but was unable to redirect my headers to the login pages.

```
if ($status == 0)
    {
        header('location:index.php?status=fail');
    }
else
    {
        if ($_SESSION['level'] == 1)
        {
            header('location:basicuser');
        }
        if ($_SESSION['level'] == 2)
        {
            header('location:prouser');
        }
        if ($_SESSION['level'] == 3)
        {
            header('location:admin');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for posting. However, we don't do general "is my code secure" code review type questions. Can you narrow your question down to a specific vulnerability or prevention technique? Thanks!

Comment: @Ohnana I've tried to improve my question!

Comment: What happens if someone goes to http://yoursite.example/admin when they aren't admin?

Comment: This code is awful. Please read [PHP the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) and use a framework.

Comment: @AndréBorie the code is much much bigger but this is in login.php after checking user/pass

Comment: @immibis they get redirected to the login page

Comment: @popopret On the admin page, when you redirect them to the login page, *that* is where there could be this vulnerability. Because if you are not careful, you might redirect the user *and* also send them secret information (which their browser won't display).

Comment: @popopret yet another reason to use a framework. It'll make the code more secure and maintainable in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with header redirects and exiting is that anything *after* the header redirect in the same script will still be executed.

You will not see it in a browser as you are being redirected, but you will see it in tools like burp or curl, which do not automatically follow a redirect.

If you do not actually execute any code after the header redirect, there is no issue (although it's best practice to just `exit`, as the code may change in the future).

<sub>Apart from that: you are using additional checks on the pages you redirect to, right? Because if not, an attacker could just enter them directly</sub>